# If IE comments showing up in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, conditional-comments

This is what is happening when you visit my site in IE9 - [image: IE9 Error]

This is the code that is causing this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/ie.css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/sizeable.css" media="screen" />
<!--[endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/sizeable.css" media="screen" />
<!--[endif]-->
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: fixed according to the commenters, thanks. See also the other answers.

---

Corrected code (second part):

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/sizeable.css" media="screen" />
<!-- <![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/sizeable.css" media="screen" />
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Actually, he does not have too many dashed, see this link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment

Comment: That "corrected" code leads to nothing ever loading the stylesheet: IE doesn't match the conditional comment (because it's `!IE`), and nothing else matches the conditional comment because it's just a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the "dashes" are correct, but first you must close the conditionals, like so:

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/sizeable.css" media="screen" />
<!-- <![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/sizeable.css" media="screen" />
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Not adding the "dashes" will cause no browser to pay attention to these conditionals. Non-IE browsers do not read comments, so the code must be outside the comment for the `!IE` condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!--<![if (IE X)|(IE Y)]--><link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /><!--<![endif]-->
```

Above conditional comment will work properly For Hiding Comment line you must have to add `<!--<!` in this format

Answer (score 1):

You're closing your comments prematurely.  Your conditional comments should open like:

```
<!--[cond]>
```

and end like:

```
<![end]-->
```

You did the first one right, but because your opening tags end with `-->`, that closes the comment right there, so the link tag, which is supposed to be part of the comment, isn't, and is interpreted as regular HTML.

Hope that helps!